# Javascript Custom Alert Box with Image alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I Have created Custom Alert Box in Javascript . I Have added text with images. but It is not align proberly. It came some thing like this. 
[image]

I am trying to add the correct mark and text with same line, how can I achieve this. can anyone please help me. I have added my Custom alert box Function below.

```
function createCustomAlert(txt, string_url,fd) {
        // shortcut reference to the document object
        d = document;

        // if the modalContainer object already exists in the DOM, bail out.
        if (d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

        // create the modalContainer div as a child of the BODY element
        mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
        mObj.id = "modalContainer";
        // make sure its as tall as it needs to be to overlay all the content on the page
        mObj.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

        // create the DIV that will be the alert 
        alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
        alertObj.id = "alertBox";
        // MSIE doesnt treat position:fixed correctly, so this compensates for positioning the alert
        if (d.all && !window.opera) alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
        // center the alert box
        alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";

        // create an H1 element as the title bar
        h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
        h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));
btn2 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("img"));
        btn2.id = "fd";
        btn2.src = fd;
        // create a paragraph element to contain the txt argument
        msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
        msg.innerHTML = txt;

        // create an anchor element to use as the confirmation button.
        //btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
        //btn.id = "closeBtn";
        //btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
        //btn.href = "";


        btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("img"));
        btn.id = "closeBtn";
        btn.src = 'new-go-next2.png';
        btn.href="#ss";
        //btn.height="30px";
        //btn.width="30px";
        //btn.href="#";


        // set up the onclick event to remove the alert when the anchor is clicked
        btn.onclick = function () { removeCustomAlert(); window.location = string_url; return false; }


    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you solve it adding vertical-align style to the image (test the posible values http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp it can be middle or text-top)

Comment: You need to have the buttons in a same line? right?

Comment: Yes, I want add buttons and text with same line....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well yes creating a table would be a great approach to solve your problems , btw u can also try some internal divs with proper position anf the element having correct float attribute

Answer (score 0):

Rather creating div element create table with two Columns. First of which will contain 'Image' for OK and Second one will contain your 'Text'.
Check if this helps.